# Alternative to reduction clause parallelizing a dependent nested for loop with OpenMP

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

Is there a way to paralellize the following code (without changing it) using OpenMP?

In this case the reduction clause cannot be used since variable 'c' is a matrix and there is a dependence between first and fourth for loops. I am not sure either whether a collapse clause would work.

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  for(j=0; j<N; j++) {   
    for(k=0; k<N; k++) {
      c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
      for(l=0; l<i+N+N; l++) {
        c[i][j] -= ((Z*k)+l-k)/(l+k+1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my OpenMP-fu is weak, but I'm not seeing the problem.  As far as I can tell, if you turn that into an omp parallel loop then no two threads executing it would ever access the same element of `c`; therefore, ensuring that (all of) `c` has 'shared' status ought to be all that you need to do.

Comment: Yes, there is no data dependency at all between any of the iterations. Trivial to parallelize with OpenMp.

Comment: You could make the reduction in the inner loop explicit with omp simd reduction.  As others said that is independent of omp parallel application to the outer loop and is likely unnecessary depending on your compiler and options.